# Custom Display Annotation based on a field value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, viewmodel

I have a View that based on a field value, must display a custom Label.

ViewModel:

```
public class CreateAdViewModel
{
     public int Operation_Id { get; set; } 

     [Display(ResourceType = typeof(HeelpResources), Name = "AdViewModel_Price_Label")]
     public decimal Price { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
    <div id="price">
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.Price)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Price) €
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Price)
    </div>
```

I want to Display:

```
"Price: "  if Operation_Id = 1 (For the Sale of a Car)
```

And

```
"Price Up To: "  if Operation_Id = 2 (For someone looking for a car until value XX €)
```

Comment: Is the field value known and non-changeable on page load?

Comment: Hi, it's defined in the first step of a wizard, and the label has to be set on the third step of the wizard, so yes, the Operation_Id will not change when we get to the third step. Hope I answer your question

Answer (score 0):

How about 2 properties:

```
public class CreateAdViewModel
{
    public int Operation_Id { get; set; }

    [Display(ResourceType = typeof(HelpResources), Name = "AdViewModel_Price_Label")]
    public decimal? Price { get; set; }

    [Display(ResourceType = typeof(HelpResources), Name = "AdViewModel_MaxPrice_Label")]
    public decimal? MaxPrice { get; set; }
}
```

and inside the view:

```
<div id="price">
    @if (Operation_Id == 1)
    {
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.Price)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Price) €
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Price)
    }
    else
    {
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.MaxPrice)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.MaxPrice) €
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.MaxPrice)
    }
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, this way I will have aditional work (in the mapping process to DTO) to insert in the database only 1 value because I think the best way is to define the label based on the Operation Type but only keep one value (Price) in the database, don't you think? Is there another solution that avoid two ViewModel fields? Thanks

Comment: Those properties should be on your view model and not on your domain model. On your domain model you could have a single property. But on view model (which is what you should be passing to the view) you could perfectly fine have 2 properties. I hope you are not passing your domain models to the view, are you?

Comment: Hi, yes of course I only have 1 property in Domain that pass to DTO and then to ViewModel. The thing here is to avoid to have an if condition if the Automapper mapping to send the value back from Viewmodel to DTO, to pass only the value that is not null, Price or MaxPrice. I would like to avoid this and have only one field, if possible of course, to avoid this change in Mapping process.